# Как сделать кулдаун после проверки?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я сделал проверку на использование команды в определенном канале, однако даже если использовать эту команду в несоответствующем канале кулдаун на нее набрасывается,как сделать срабатывание кулдауна после проверки?

```
@client.command(aliases = ['honor'])
@commands.has_role('Дозорный')
@commands.cooldown(1, 900, commands.BucketType.user)
async def __add2(ctx,member:discord.Member = None):
    message = ctx.message
    if message.channel.id != тут id канала:
        await ctx.send('Эта команда недоступна на данном канале,используйте её в соответствующем канале')
    else:
        if member is None:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users2 SET honor = honor+75000 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
            embed= discord.Embed(description = f"""Репутация **{ctx.author}** была повышена на 75000 очков!""",color = 0x000000,)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            connection.commit()
```